# How to find chemical formulas with regex

Tags: regex, scientific-notation

This problem might not be a specific programming issue but, I try to find chemical formulas like H20, C02 etc. in a scientic text and I use this:

```
(?<=[\l\u]|\.)\d+
```

This works - but now also every floating point number after the 'dot' is found:

```
0.1234 -> 1234 is selected.
```

Is there a chance to prevent this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe remove the dot from the lookbehind?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?  SMILES formatted strings?  Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Just chemical formulas like H20 or SO2, see edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also include a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to prevent a preceding dot with a digit before it:

```
(?<=[\l\u.])(?<!\d\.)\d+
```

Comment: It looks like this works! I give it some more testing before I accept, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to also match strings like `H2O`, `CH3CH2CH2CH3`, `SiO2` you could use:

```
(?i)\b[a-z]+(?:\d+[a-z]+)*\b
```

or

```
\b(?:[A-Z][a-z]?)+(?:\d+(?:[A-Z][a-z]?)+)*\b
```